# pgAdmin3 backup over ssh tunnel

Tags: postgresql, backup, pgadmin, ssh-tunnel

I have a running postgresql server on amazone ec2. I connect with pgAdmin3 to it over ssh tunnel directly configured in pgAdmin3 from my mac.
I can make queries and see the full schema, no problem about that.

If I try to make a backup of the database (from pgAdmin3 GUI) then I get (even if the connection is actually open and working) the following exception:

```html
/Applications/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 --username "MY_USERNAME" --role "MY_ROLE" --no-password  --format custom --encoding UTF8 --verbose --file "/Users/XXX/filename" "DATABASENAME"
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "DATABASENAME" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Process ended with Exitcode 1.
```

Any idea why pg_dump in the background can not connect over the ssh tunnel?

Comment: I am also wondering why pgAdmin does not support this functionality. Is it a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

alternative until i found a solution is to make it by terminal

```
ssh <HOST> "pg_dump -U <USERNAME> -W -h localhost -F c <DATABASENAME> | gzip -c" > ./backup.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

This line worked for me:

```
ssh -o "Compression=no" server_adress "pg_dump -Z9 -Fc -U postgres db_name" > backup_name.dump
```